# Identifying gauge of unmarked stranded wire

Tags: electrical, range

We're replacing our range and I want to confirm that the wire size is adequate. The existing wires are part of a cable which is not visible in the panel or outlet and the wires themselves appear to be unmarked.

Is there a reliable way to determine the size of the wire? I seem to recall that US wire gauge is the number of turns per inch – so for 8 gauge wire (16 KW range) would I expect a diameter of about 0.125" (1/8) or will it be different for stranded wire?

Answer (score 2):

Wire gauge is based upon the conductor cross sectional area of the wire. There are [tables all over the internet](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) that show the characteristics of wire. [Here is one for stranded wire.](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~ecelabs/appnotes/PDF/techdat/swc.pdf)

For a given conductor cross sectional area the solid wire will have the smallest effective diameter. Stranded wire will have a slightly larger outside diameter due to the small spaces that exist between individual conductors. Different stranding (number and size of the individual conductors) will lead to different outside diameters because certain strandings will pack tighter together than others.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do if you're not sure might be to go buy a 1' piece of stranded 8 AWG wire for comparison.  There are some tiny variations but it should be very close to the same size.

If you're careful you can use a good quality wire stripper as a gauge but it's not a perfect method.  You really have to make sure you don't nick or damage the conductor by checking it.  With stranded wire you also have to make sure the wire isn't deformed or untwisted where you're checking.

[image: http://www.kleintools.com/sites/all/product_assets/catalog_imagery/klein/11049.jpg]